# Setting up Yarn High Availability (HA) in pseudo-distributed mode

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I'm a student and started a new research project that involves Hadoop.

I've been trying to setup Yarn HA in a single machine (my personal computer with Ubuntu 16.04) for some tests. It is being very hard to find reports of ResourceManager HA tests on a single node (this [link](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.4/bk_hadoop-high-availability/content/ha-rm-testing-single-node.html) is one of a few that have some info about that).

My Hadoop (currently with version 2.7.5, I already tried with 2.9 but got the same problems) configurations are:

- etc/hadoop/core-site.xml:

  ```
  <configuration>
      <property>
          <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
          <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
      </property>
  </configuration>
  ```
- etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml:

  ```
  <configuration>
      <property>
          <name>dfs.replication</name>
          <value>1</value>
      </property>
  </configuration>
  ```

Yarn configurations:

- etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml

  ```
   <configuration>
      <property>
          <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
          <value>yarn</value>
      </property>
  </configuration>
  ```
- etc/hadoop/yarn-site.xml

Here I tried a lot of different configurations, because I was thinking that there are some problems with port numbers or hostnames. In this context, I have tried editing the base configuration showed in [here](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.4/bk_hadoop-high-availability/content/ha-rm-testing-single-node.html) and edit it following the instructions of the yarn configuration parameters in [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.3/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml).  Actually, I am a bit confused about the addresses that I should use for the RMs (is it really localhost?).

```
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
    </property>

    <!-- H.A. -->
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.ha.enabled</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.cluster-id</name>
        <value>yarn-cluster</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.ha.rm-ids</name>
        <value>rm1,rm2</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname.rm1</name>
        <value>localhost</value> 
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname.rm2</name>
        <value>localhost</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.recovery.enabled</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <!-- RM1 Configs -->
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address.rm1</name>
        <value>localhost:23140</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address.rm1</name>
        <value>localhost:23130</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address.rm1</name>
        <value>localhost:23188</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address.rm1</name>
        <value>localhost:23125</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.admin.address.rm1</name>
        <value>localhost:23141</value>
    </property>

    <!-- RM2 configs -->
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address.rm2</name>
        <value>localhost:33140</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address.rm2</name>
        <value>localhost:33130</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address.rm2</name>
        <value>localhost:33188</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address.rm2</name>
        <value>localhost:33125</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.admin.address.rm2</name>
        <value>localhost:33141</value>
    </property>
```

So, I tried run:

```
$ yarn rmadmin -getServiceState rm1
```

But I got connection exception every single time. Like as follow:

```
18/04/05 21:49:59 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:23141. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=1, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)

Operation failed: Call From hadoop-pc/127.0.1.1 to localhost:23141 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused;

For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

Could anyone give me some help? I really don't know what I am doing wrong or what I can do for fix it.

EDIT:
Is it possible to set up Yarn HA in a single machine? I was thinking in a way to use Zookeeper to do it, but now I am not sure if that could work.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Setting up HA on localhost doesn't make sense

Comment: YARN tests HA on single nodes for unit tests.  You can look at: https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-server/hadoop-yarn-server-tests/src/test/java/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/server/TestMiniYarnCluster.java#L113 to see if you're missing a conf setting.

Comment: @divibisan hello, the error is: 
18/04/05 21:49:59 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:23141. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=1, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
Operation failed: Call From hadoop-pc/127.0.1.1 to localhost:23141 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused

Comment: @cricket_007 could you explain, please? Aren't there any way to setting up HA in pseudo-distributed mode?

Comment: @tk421 hi, thanks. I checked every conf and edited the yarn-site.xml, but the result as the same.

Comment: You need to remove the line containing `127.0.1.1` from all `/etc/hosts` files in your cluster. Also, I strongly recommend not using localhost ever in a configuration file. Always use the external domain name or static IP. Aldo run `jps` to verify services are actual running, `netstat` for running ports, and `telnet` for connections, as that link in the error states